# A SQL query that returns the type and value of each record, grouped by type, but only for the records that match the current date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, filter, group-by

I have a table that contains records of different types and values. I want to write a SQL query that can retrieve the type and value of each record, but only for the records that have the same date as today.

I also want to group the results by type, so that I can see how many records of each type I have for today.
**Additionally, I want to include all the types in the result, even if they have no records for today.**

```
SELECT COUNT(id), 
       STATUS
FROM http_log as hl
WHERE CAST(hl.created_at AS DATE) = CAST(current_date AS DATE)
GROUP BY STATUS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to left join the distinct status values with your query so you can get the status groups with 0 rows:

```
WITH distinct_status as
(
  SELECT DISTINCT status from http_log
)
SELECT COUNT(hl.id),
       DS.status
FROM distinct_status AS DS LEFT JOIN http_log AS hl
ON DS.status = hl.status AND 
   CAST(hl.created_at AS DATE) = current_date
GROUP BY DS.status
```

For groups that have no match rows, the `hl.id` will be null and the count will be 0.

[see a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ck1JIKRN)